# Arithmetic mean for time series

Tags: means

I wonder if I can use arithmetic mean in this case:
I have monthly indices from 2004 to 2010. I want to compute arithmetic mean for all this period to show which index has bigger or lower rate of change. Is this procedure correct?

I have some doubts and I consider two more solutions. Maybe this procedure will be better: firstly, compute mean for each year and then mean of yearly means?

Comment: If you use arithmetic means, make sure they're on log-returns.

Comment: even if my indices are y-o-y indices?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about finance to understand your notation. Basically, we want to think about $\ln\frac{y}{y_0}$ if $y$ is a price, or $y-y0$ if $y$ is a log-price.

Comment: I think the OP means 'year-on-year indices'.